# Bad operand types 'std_ulogic' and 'string(1 to 1)' from vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I've this error on my code at the line 13 and 27, on vhdl, do anyone know what's wrong?

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity POLI is 
    port(A,B: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
         x,y: in std_logic;
         S: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0));
end POLI;

architecture codigo of POLI is
    begin
        process(x) begin
            if (x="1") then
                S(0)<=((A(0)and(not A(1))and A(2))or((not A(0))and A(1)and A(2)));
                S(1)<=((not A(0))and A(1)and (not A(2)));
                S(2)<=((not A(0))and (not A(2)));
                S(3)<=(((not A(0))and (not A(1))and (not A(2)))or ((not A(0))and A(1)and A(2)));
                S(4)<=(A(0)and (not A(1))and (not A(2)));
                S(5)<=(A(0)and (not A(1))and (not A(2)));
                S(6)<=(((not A(0))and A(1))or((not A(0))and A(2)));
            else
                S<="0000000";
            end if;
        end process;

        process(y) begin
            if (y="1") then
                S(1)<=(((not B(0))and (not B(2)))or((not b(0))and(not B(1))));
                S(2)<=((not B(0))and(not B(2)));
                S(4)<=(((not B(1))and B(0))or((not B(1))and B(2)));
                S(5)<=(B(0)and(not B(1)));
                S(6)<=(((not B(0))and B(1)));
             else
                S<="-------";
            end if;
        end process;
end codigo;
```

I tried on other computers and compilers, and all got the same problem

Comment: I'm surprised anyone is till using a WARP tool today. `E601 :Bad operand types '%s' and '%s' for operator '%s'.`

Comment: A character enumeration type (std_ulogic) has values that are character literal overloads ('U', 'X', '0', '1', 'Z', 'W', 'L', 'H', '-'), in package std_logic_1164. IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.2.2 Enumeration types "If the same identifier or character literal is specified in more than one enumeration type definition, the corresponding literals are said to be *overloaded*. At any place where an overloaded enumeration literal occurs in the text of a program, the type of the enumeration literal is determined according to the rules for overloaded subprograms (see 4.5)." x is declared std_ulogic.

Comment: 9.3.2 Literals "String and bit string literals are representations of one-dimensional arrays of characters. The type of a string or bit string literal shall be determinable solely from the context in which the literal appears, excluding the literal itself but using the fact that the type of the literal shall be a one-dimensional array of a character type." A string literal isn't a value of an enumerated type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `if x="1" then` and `if y = "1" then`
`""` In VHDL represents a string (or a bitstring literal)
both `x` and `y` are `std_logic` and hence not array types.
In this instance, you should use `'`, as this is the character reference that `std_logic` uses for its values.

hence you should write.

```vhdl
if x = '1' then
....
if y = '1' then
```

Comment: surprising, im using vivado or diamond and when i make mistakes like that i dont even have to synthetize to see it, the line is underlined in red